# 26 pointers per node in trie?

Tags: pointers, nodes, trie

I am learning about data structures on geeksforgeeks.org and there were some points on ternary search trees and tries that I didn't understand:

> Unlike trie(standard) data structure where each node contains 26 pointers for its children, each node in a ternary search tree contains only 3 pointers[.]

and

> One of the advantage of using ternary search trees over tries is that ternary search trees are a more space efficient (involve only three pointers per node as compared to 26 in standard tries).

Could someone explain why each node is supposed to have 26 pointers in a trie? I've tried searching for the difference between tries and ternary search trees, but I still don't understand this point.

Thanks.

(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/)

Comment: I'm guessing that search tree is for text, as there are 26 letters in the alphabet.

Comment: But shouldn't that only be the case for lexicons in which all 26 letters are present in a word-terminal position?

I also don't understand why it would be 26 PER node. Maybe just unclear writing?

Comment: I find it strange that the quote talks about pointers of  a trie as a defining feature of that data structure is that the position within the array defines the tree rather than explicit pointers.

Comment: They probably mean their own article, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-tries/